# Hide null values when returning oData object

Tags: c#, .net, odata

I have the below code that gets its data from a SQL view, and makes use of odata so that we can query the data by making use of a querystring in our get request.

The problem I have is that **Author** is nullable but I don't want it to display if it is null. I can't get away from mapping it the way that I currently am and adding ternery operators into it too hide the null data breaks the **Queryable** feature.

```cs
[HttpGet]
[CustomEnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = Filter | Skip | Top | OrderBy | Count | Select, PageSize = 100)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(IQueryable<BookViewModel>), Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ProblemDetails), Status400BadRequest)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ProblemDetails), Status401Unauthorized)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ProblemDetails), Status404NotFound)]
public IQueryable<BookViewModel> Get()
{
    return _defaultContext.Books
                          .AsQueryable()
                          .Select(x => new BookViewModel
                          {
                              BookId = x.BookId,
                              BookName= x.BookName,
                              BookPrice= x.BookPrice,
                              PublishingCompany= x.PublishingCompany,
                              Author = new Author 
                              {
                                  AuthorName = x.AuthorName,
                                  Birthday = x.Birthday
                              }
                          });
}
```

The above code returns this when author is null:

```json
{
    "BookId ": "f726bcf7-e4f6-4609-b25e-a0d47cda7894",
    "BookName": "Atomic Habits",
    "BookPrice": "500",
    "PublishingCompany": "Penguin",
        "Author ": {
            "AuthorName": null,
            "Birthday": null,
        }
}
```

How would I either hide Author all together when null or display Author as null without the mapped out values also displaying as null?

Answer (score -2):

you can use `??` operator that equals to `if (obj == null) obj = "something else"`

```
.......
Author = new Author 
{
     AuthorName = x.AuthorName ?? "",
     Birthday = x.Birthday ?? ""
}
......
```

Comment: this is a null-coalescing operator and is similar to the ternery operator mentioned in my original question. I can't use these in the iqueryable object as it causes it to break